# How to exclude URL parameters from Google Analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, url-parameters, universal-analytics, query-string

The number of unique URLs on our site exceeds the limit in our Google Analytics. We tried to exclude URL Query Parameters in the View Settings but it doesn't work, GA continue to record all of them as unique URLs.

[image]

How do we limit the number of URLs in Google Analytics by removing the query string from all URLs?

Comment: If you don't find an answer for how to do it on the GA side, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922731/google-analytics-intercept-all-requests and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks for examples of modifying the library and removing the querystring before it's sent.

Answer (score 2):

Only `?` indicates a query parameter; adding `f` to the exclusion list would remove `?f=...` parts of a URL but won't affect `/f/...`.

You should be able to do this with a filter, though. Add a new filter of type Custom > Search and Replace, using the field Request URI and the search string `/f/.*`.

Filters are destructive, meaning they permanently alter your data with no way to recover the original information. Therefore a recommendation: Apply the filter to a testing view first, and before saving, verify the filter to make sure it is not causing side effects. Add it to your primary view only after it's well-tested. (And of course it is always best to have a view that has no filters on it at all, and no query parameter removal.)

[image: Screenshot of filter setup]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `fbclid, msclkid, page_id, preview_id, cm` you write `fbclid,msclkid,p=,page_id,preview_id,cm`. Remove the spaces, it might help.